# Hibernate Slow Startup

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Tomcat to deploy the server but when i startup my server, after the user tried to Login the page **it takes like 2-3 seconds too connect/show next page**. I'm only checking if the hashed password is on the database, nothing else. This is a fresh code and it's all local so it must be some configurations that are making this slow.

When the user clicks the button to login I do `GetSessionFactory()`

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory factory;

static {

    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
public static SessionFactory GetSessionFactory() {
    return factory;
}
}
```

Comment: If you're noticing this slowness only on the first login after deploying your application, its likely due to the fact its the first time you're access `HibernateUtil` and thus when static initialization occurs.  Its during this initialization that your Hibernate configuration is read and the `SessionFactory` gets constructed.  You could build the `SessionFactory` during deployment instead so that the static initialization occurs then rather than when you first login.

Comment: What do you mean by that? I asked on this forum and people told me to do like this.

Comment: You might want to read up on when static initialization blocks in java classes are executed.  What I am saying is that code executes when your code first accesses `HibernateUtil`, which may be when your code executes the `#GetSessionFactory()` for the very first time.  After that, the static block has already been executed, so subsequent calls to that method won't incur the init cost.  That init cost comes into play by reading the Hibernate configuration, entity mappings, and building the session factory and metamodel necessary for Hibernate's runtime.

Comment: In short, make sure you build that `SessionFactory` when your application initializes, not when your code first forces the JVM to load `HibernateUtil`.